# django liveservertestcase error

Tags: django-testing, django-tests

I am trying to run django tests in my app.
My app is "accounts" and after I run the tests using the command
"python manage.py test accounts " 
it creates a test database which is apt. So the default port for testing is localhost:8081.  But then when tests go the login function with the url "locahost:8081/accounts/login" I don't see the login page and it shows a blank page. I get the error saying

`NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id_username"}' ; Stacktrace: Method FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ threw an error in file:///tmp/tmpfJYYIZ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js` 
So I think it couldn't load the login page and so it didn't find the id_username(This is the id for text box in login page).

I thought may be it couldn't load the "localhost:8081" so i added it to the django_site database table in setUpClass of the tests.py . But still it didn't work.

I also tried adding the "localhost:8081" in fixtures and include it in tests.py .It didn't help either.

Any ideas please.??